# PHP (cli) swallows a byte when reading from /dev/tty

Tags: php, bash, tty

I am having an issue with PHP (cli) when using `/dev/tty` as the file. The actual scenario is slightly more complex and is not mentioned here to keep the question simple.

To run PHP code from STDIN, I am able to run the command as follows,

```
$ php
<?php
echo "hello world\n";
?>
<CTRL-D>
hello world
$
```

However, when run through `/dev/tty`, the following happens,

```
$ php /dev/tty
<?php
echo "hello world\n";
?>
<CTRL-D>
?php
echo "hello world\n";
?>
$
```

**NOTE:** The first character `<` is simply lost and php processes the input as plain text. We can simplify the test to the following,

**Working**

```
$ php
abcd
abcd
$
```

**Not Working**

```
$ php /dev/tty
abcd
bcd
$
```

I have run `strace` to check if php reads the input correctly and it seems to be so, as shown below,

```
$ strace -o /tmp/1 php /dev/tty ; grep "bcd" /tmp/1
abcd
<CTRL-D>
bcd
read(4, "abcd\n", 4096)                 = 5
write(1, "bcd\n", 4)                    = 4
$
```

This seems pretty simple and, I feel, I am missing something very basic here.

Does anyone know why PHP (cli) behaves this way when reading from /dev/tty ?

**Additional Info:-**

- PHP Versions: 5.3.3 (cli) and 5.5.20 (cli)
- OS: Linux (CentOS 6.4 and Fedora 19)

Comment: It may or may not be relevant, but can you tell use the version of PHP you're using, and also details about the OS.

Comment: I tried the above with php 5.6.10 and it exhibits the same behavior - the `<` is "eaten".

Answer (score -1):

`php /dev/tty
\<?php
echo "hi\n";
?>
hi`

Escaping the `<` worked. I don't know why though :D Probably related to the fact that this is in ran in bash.

Comment: Probably because *the first character is swallowed* and you could probably put *anything* there...!?

Comment: @deceze yeah that might be true too :)